# How to use on select and keyup event on same function using jquery ?

Tags: jquery

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#where_to_go").autocomplete({
            source: "search_city.php",
            select: function (event, ui) 
            {
                item_val =  ui.item.value;
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{"item_val":item_val},
                    url:"<?php $root_path_main; ?>get-city.php",
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I have create an autocomplete textbox which is work fine but the problem is that I want to use on select and keyup function on same function and alert value. Now, I am using only select function to get autocomplete value which is working but I want to use keyup function also. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Your explanation is quite hard to understand, could you post screenshots so we can understand it better?

Comment: ? Screenshots? Is that the new thing on SO?

Comment: @omkara If you want to add multiple events on the same function then try like this ` $("#where_to_go").on('select keyup', function(){ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `search` function with autocomplete like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#where_to_go").autocomplete({
        source: "search_city.php",
        select: function (event, ui) 
        {
            item_val =  ui.item.value;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"item_val":item_val},
                url:"<?php $root_path_main; ?>get-city.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        },
        search: function(event, ui)
        {
             alert(123);     //For testing.
             //Your code
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps if I understood your question.